# Rewriting PHP files in sub-directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess file to block requests to PHP files and display the 404.php file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index|backup).php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(dir1|dir1)\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.php
RewriteRule .* 404.php [L]
```

This blocks requests to all PHP files with the exception of index.php, backup.php and any files in dir1 and dir2. This works for requests at the root:

```
http://www.example.com/some-file.php
http://www.example.com/another-file.php
```

But it doesn't work for files in sub-directories:

```
http://www.example.com/sub/some-file.php
http://www.example.com/sub/another-file.php
```

I should say that the sub-directory 'sub' doesn't actually exist. The requests are coming from automated scanners looking to find holes in the site. I am rewriting the requests to 404.php as this file doesn't load the database or any of the application. If I don't do this, the full application 404 is loaded instead, which keeps crashing MySQL as I get 100's of these requests a minute (several times a day).

My question then is how can I modify the code to work for sub-directories? I thought that the REQUEST_URI included the full sub-directory in it so the code should work as is?

Answer (score -1):

You could have a separate rewriterule that just denies access to `sub`, put this before your other rules and it will just 403 the request and stop processing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(sub.*|othersub.*)$ 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I would keep a separate list like this to deny because people fishing for exploits falls into the 403 category, whereas a genuine mistake looking for a potentially valid url is more of a 404.

Comment: This won't work as the directories don't really exist and can be anything as they are being requested via automated exploit scanners. I don't have a specific list of dirs to block. It's not an issue for me to block all .php files as the only valid PHP file on the server is index.php, which is allowed using this rule.